# having trouble to encode hebrew into url for google maps query

Tags: javascript, json, r, google-maps, urlencode

I have a little R code that takes the city name that I supply to it and then inputs that into an URL-query type that Google Maps can understand, and then it gives me the latitude and the longitude coordinates. My city names are all in Hebrew!

When I use "url encode" in [this](https://www.hashemian.com/tools/html-url-encode-decode.php) site and then put the output to my code everything works well. But then I thought to myself - why do I need to use this site when I can encode it by R in the same code.

So I tried that, and apperantly - `URLencode` and all the packages that I have found on the internet are encoding it **differently** than the website I have mentioned. For example:
I want to encode the hebrew city name:`צפת`

- output from website:

  `%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%AA`.
- output from `URLencode`:

  `%F6%F4%FA`

How can I get the first encoding that the website uses?
(I have tried to use `RCurl` and `urltools`, all to no avail..)

The R code is this (I found it on [this](http://allthingsr.blogspot.co.il/2012/01/geocode-your-data-using-r-json-and.html) website):

```
getGeoCode <- function(gcStr)
{
  library("RJSONIO") # Load Library
  gcStr <- gsub(' ','%20',gcStr) # Encode URL Parameters
  # Open Connection
  connectStr <- paste('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=',gcStr, sep="") 
  con <- url(connectStr)
  data.json <- fromJSON(paste(readLines(con), collapse=""))
  close(con)
  # Flatten the received JSON
  data.json <- unlist(data.json)
  lat <- data.json["results.geometry.location.lat"]
  lng <- data.json["results.geometry.location.lng"]
  gcodes <- c(lat, lng)
  names(gcodes) <- c("Lat", "Lng")
  return (gcodes)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I've managed to find the answer to my problem - I had to change my locale to "English" because it was on "Hebrew". `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")`

Answer (score 1):

I'm not seeing the issue you're describing with `URLencode()`:

```
location <- "צפת"
URLencode(location)
# [1] "%D7%A6%D7%A4%D7%AA"
```

And using my `googleway` package the query to Google works

```
library(googleway)

apiKey <- ""

res <- google_geocode(address = location, key = apiKey)

res$results$formatted_address
# [1] "Safed, Israel"

res$results$address_components
# [[1]]
# long_name     short_name                                  types
# 1          Safed          Safed                    locality, political
# 2          Tzfat          Tzfat administrative_area_level_2, political
# 3 North District North District administrative_area_level_1, political
# 4         Israel             IL                     country, political

res$results$geometry$location
#        lat    lng
# 1 32.96465 35.496
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - first of all I did not know about the googleway package. I used a function. Anyway I managed to find the answer to my problem - I had to change my locale to "English" because it was on "Hebrew". `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")`

Comment: @Corel - you should add that as an answer because it may help someone else in the future.